# Normal packet-reception ratio for TCP/IP

Tags: tcp

I have an experiment set-up using two laptop machines , one acting as a transmitter and another as receiver. The transmitter continuously transmits packets of different sizes , depending on the time period of different timers that have been configured. The receiver captures these packets and calculates the PRR upon termination of the program.

The transmitter and receiver are separated by a distance of about just 6-7 feet

Is a packet-reception ratio of 0.87 normal for this TCP/IP set-up or is it on the lower side?

Transmitter:

```
 void sendMedicalStream(void) {

  timer_count ++;

  if(timer_count % 5 ==0) {        

  memcpy(pu8 ,(struct pulse_oxim_packet*)& oxim_packet , sizeof(struct 
              pulse_oxim_packet));
   x=send(s,pu8,sizeof(u8aSendBuffer),0); 
  }

  if(timer_count % 50 == 0) {    
   memcpy(pu8 ,(struct ecg_data*)& wifi_ecg_data , sizeof(struct ecg_data));
   x=send(s,pu8,sizeof(u8aSendBuffer),0);
  }

   if(timer_count % 10 == 0) {  
   memcpy(pu8 ,(struct resp_monitor_packet*)& rsp_mon_packet , sizeof(struct   
                                                              resp_monitor_packet));
   x=send(s,pu8,sizeof(u8aSendBuffer),0);
    }

    if(timer_count % 120 == 0) {  
    memcpy(pu8 ,(struct self_check_glucose_monitor_packet*)& gm_packet , sizeof(struct 
                           self_check_glucose_monitor_packet));
    x=send(s,pu8,sizeof(u8aSendBuffer),0);
   }

     if(timer_count % 30 == 0) {  
    memcpy(pu8 ,(struct self_check_weight_monitor*)& wm_packet , sizeof(struct 
                                                   self_check_weight_monitor));
     x=send(s,pu8,sizeof(u8aSendBuffer),0);
    }

  if(timer_count % 25 == 0) {  
   memcpy(pu8 ,(struct asthma_monitor*)& as_mon_packet , sizeof(struct asthma_monitor));
   x=send(s,pu8,sizeof(u8aSendBuffer),0);
   }

  if(timer_count % 35 == 0) {  
    memcpy(pu8 ,(struct  sc_blood_press_mon_packet*)& bp_mon_packet , sizeof(struct 
                      sc_blood_press_mon_packet));
    x=send(s,pu8,sizeof(u8aSendBuffer),0);
  }

 if(timer_count % 45 == 0) {  
  memcpy(pu8 ,(struct  insulin_pump_packet*)& ins_pump_packet , sizeof(struct 
                         insulin_pump_packet));
   x=send(s,pu8,sizeof(u8aSendBuffer),0);
  }


  if(timer_count % 15 == 0) { 
   memcpy(pu8 ,(struct  fetal_heart_monitor *)& fhm_packet , sizeof(struct 
                            fetal_heart_monitor));
    x=send(s,pu8,sizeof(u8aSendBuffer),0);
  }
   if(timer_count % 180 == 0) {  
   memcpy(pu8 ,(struct dialysis_machine *)& dial_mach_packet , sizeof(struct 
                      dialysis_machine));
   x=send(s,pu8,sizeof(u8aSendBuffer),0);

  }

  if(timer_count == 10000)
   timer_count = 0;
  }

 int main(int argc,char **argv)
  {

struct sockaddr_in sin;

 /* Packet Title DEtails */
    strcpy(fhm_packet.title,"Fetal-Heart-Rate-Monitor");
    strcpy(bp_mon_packet.title,"Blood-Pressure-Monitor");
    strcpy(ins_pump_packet.title,"Insulin-Pump-Monitor");
    strcpy(wm_packet.title,"Weight-Monitor");
    strcpy(as_mon_packet.title,"Asthma-Monitor");
    strcpy(gm_packet.title,"Glucose-Level-Monitor");
    strcpy(rsp_mon_packet.title,"Infant-Respiratory-Monitor");
    strcpy(dial_mach_packet.title,"Dialysis-Machine");


    /* Socket Details */   
    len=sizeof(struct sockaddr);

    if(argc==2){
    host =argv[1];
    }

   /* translates the host name into peer's IP address */

   hp=gethostbyname(host);
    if(!hp){
    fprintf(stderr,"duplex-talk : uknown host : %s\n",host);
    exit(1);
    }

   /* build address data structures */

    bzero((char *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy(hp->h_addr,(char *)(&sin.sin_addr),hp->h_length);
    sin.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

     /* active open */
    if((s = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0) {
    perror("duplex-talk : socket");
    exit(1);
     }

    if(connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin)) <0) {
    perror("duplex-talk : connect");
    exit(1);
   }


  /* Timer Details */

  struct itimerval it_val;  /* for setting itimer */

   if (signal(SIGALRM, (void (*)(int)) sendMedicalStream) == SIG_ERR) {
   perror("Unable to catch SIGALRM");
    exit(1);
   }


   it_val.it_value.tv_sec =     MIN_INTERVAL/1000;
   it_val.it_value.tv_usec =    (MIN_INTERVAL*1000) % 1000000;   
   it_val.it_interval = it_val.it_value;

   if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &it_val, NULL) == -1) {
   perror("error calling ECG setitimer()");
   exit(1);
   }


 /* main loop : get and send lines of text */
  int i=0,j=0;  
 while(1);

 }
```

Receiver :

```
 int main(int argc,char *argv)
  {
   char * pu8 = u8aSendBuffer;
   signal(SIGINT,INThandler);
struct sockaddr_in sin;
struct sockaddr addr;
socklen_t fromlen;
char buf[MAX_LINE];


len=sizeof(struct sockaddr);

/* build address data structues */

bzero((char *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
sin.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

/* setup passive open*/

if((s=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0) { 
      perror("duplex-talk:socket");
       exit(1);
   }

   if((bind(s,(struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin))) < 0){

    perror("duplex-talk: bind");
    exit(1);
   }

    // listen
  listen(s,MAX_PENDING);

    if((new_s = accept(s,(struct sockaddr *)&sin, &len)) < 0) {
    perror("duplex-talk : accept");
     exit(1);
  }

  while(1)
  {


    recv(new_s,pu8,sizeof(u8aSendBuffer),0);

    p_ptr = (struct pulse_oxim_packet *)pu8;
    ecg_ptr = (struct ecg_data *)pu8;
    resp_mon_ptr = (struct resp_monitor_packet *)pu8;
    gmon_ptr = (struct self_check_glucose_monitor_packet *)pu8;
    wmon_ptr = (struct self_check_weight_monitor *)pu8;
    asmon_ptr = (struct asthma_monitor *)pu8;
    bp_mon_ptr = (struct sc_blood_press_mon_packet *)pu8;
    ins_pump_packet = (struct insulin_pump_packet *)pu8;
    ft_mon_ptr = (struct fetal_heart_monitor *) pu8; 
    dial_mach_ptr = (struct dialysis_machine *) pu8;     



  if( p_ptr != NULL && strcmp(p_ptr->title,"Pulse-Oximeter-Data") == 0) 
    recv_count++;
  if( ecg_ptr != NULL &&  strcmp( ecg_ptr->title,"ECG-Monitor-Data") == 0 )
    recv_count++;
  if( gmon_ptr != NULL &&  strcmp( gmon_ptr->title,"Glucose-Level-Monitor") == 0 )
     recv_count++;
  if( asmon_ptr != NULL &&  strcmp( asmon_ptr->title,"Asthma-Monitor") == 0 )
     recv_count++;
  if(wmon_ptr != NULL &&  strcmp( wmon_ptr->title,"Weight-Monitor") == 0 )
     recv_count++;
    if( ins_pump_packet != NULL && strcmp( ins_pump_packet->title,"Insulin-Pump-Monitor") 
                             == 0)
     recv_count++;
  if( bp_mon_ptr != NULL &&  strcmp(bp_mon_ptr->title,"Blood-Pressure-Monitor") == 0 )
     recv_count++;
  if( ft_mon_ptr != NULL &&  strcmp( ft_mon_ptr->title,"Fetal-Heart-Rate-Monitor") == 0 )
     recv_count++;
   if( dial_mach_ptr != NULL &&  strcmp( dial_mach_ptr->title,"Dialysis-Machine") == 0 )
     recv_count++;
   }

   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Are you using TCP or UDP?  I suspect UDP, because with TCP you really shouldn't lose any packets as TCP will re-transmit any lost packets.  Are you also using wireless as you mention the distance between the computers?

Comment: I am using TCP sockets.. and Wifi is the communication medium..

Comment: @hektor: So how exactly are you measuring this loss? Is it the number of retransmits required, or are you genuinely losing *data*?

Comment: @ HeatFanJohn : I think i am losing data packets. I am encoding a sequence number in every packet that i transmit and checking the sequence number of the packets that i receive. At times there seems to be a burst loss of about 7-8 packets.

Comment: @hektor: I think it would really help if you'd show the code you're using - because fundamentally with TCP you normally don't get involved at the packet level.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I've edited my post to include the code. Please point any any mistakes that you can find.

Comment: @hektor: See the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a networking expert, but if your transmitter is *continuously* transmitting packets, it's quite possibly introducing far more interference with ACK packets than would normally be the case.

My guess is that if you modify it very slightly so that it doesn't saturate the connection, you'll find you get a much higher packet reception ratio.

EDIT: Having seen your code, I believe one possible problem is that even though you've *created* a stream-based socket, you're not *treating* it as one - you're assuming that you'll get exactly one packet on each `recv` call:

```
recv(new_s,pu8,sizeof(u8aSendBuffer),0);
```

You should be using the return value from `recv` to see how many bytes have *actually* been received.

It's *possible* that you're semi-okay to ignore it in this case due to having a very small receiving window (I don't know what `sizeof(u8aSendBuffer)` is) but in generally you should *not* be treating the stream as a sequence of packets like you are: you should treat it as a stream of data, where you may or may not receive as much data as you ask for.